# How many times can i compose a md5 function with itself?

Tags: security, hash, brute-force, md5sum

For *studying* purposes it would be usefull to find out how many times can i compose a md5 function with itself **without getting the same value**.

This is a paralell/complementary approach to the salt, because this way the value gets harder to crack using brute force.

Comment: you mean something like `while(foo != md5(foo)) { foo = md5(foo) }`? While md5 is useless these days, I doubt it was ever so fundamentally broken that `foo == md5(foo)` would ever be true.

Comment: That's mathematically impossible. MD5 relation set is finite. And as a result, you'll return more elements than existent in the relation. (16^32 values) There are many values, but that's exactly the point of my question: how many times can i do it?

Comment: Any other statistic/data/study (for sha1 for example) would be as useful.

Comment: Yes, the inputs are infinite. But once you start feeding the outputs back as inputs, you're instantly limiting yourself to 2^128 inputs, because that's all that md5 ever will output. A hash function which generates an output that's identical to itself as an input is useless.

Comment: You have to take into account two things: 1. It doesn't matter how many inputs (infinite) it has, only matters the output which is finite. 2. Choose the composition function you want: md5, substr . md5, reverse . substr . md5. It doesn't matter. Each composition has a recursion limit.

Answer (score 4):

Seemingly infinite. However MD5 has been shown to not be [collision resistant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistant) so at some point you will have a duplicate.

The following Ruby code will cyclicly apply the MD5 hashing algorithm until a duplicate has been detected, at which point it will print the number of cycles required to reach the duplication point. The original string is randomly generated from alphabetical characters.

```
require 'set'
require 'digest'

keys = Set.new

o = [('a'..'z'), ('A'..'Z')].map { |i| i.to_a }.flatten
string = (0...10).map{ o[rand(o.length)] }.join
count = 0

while !keys.include?(string) do
  count += 1
  puts count
  keys << string
  string = Digest::MD5.digest(string)
end

puts "#{count}"
```

This continues to run past 15mil cycles... I will update once a duplicate has been found.

**Update:** due to the limited resources of my machine I had to halt the above script after 75,933,338 cycles without a collision (the set had allocated ~8 GB in memory)

Comment: This seems to be an useful way of measuring it but maybe using a tree-like datatype on disc.

Comment: Not a proof by any means, but good anecdotal evidence and a good answer overall.

Comment: I just wanted to illustrate how hard it is to actually produce a duplicate in a real world trial.